# Dealing with negative roots in code

Tags: quadratics

I have an equation in the following form that needs to be solved for $x$, with $x > 0$ and constants $a,b,c,d \geq 0$.

$\left(\frac{x - a}{b}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{x - c}{d}\right)^2 = 1$

From the following paper, which i am trying to implement:
https://grail.cs.washington.edu/projects/crowd-flows/78-treuille.pdf

Wolfram Alpha gives the following solution:

$x = \frac{\sqrt{b^2 d^2 (-a^2 + 2 a c + b^2 - c^2 + d^2} + a d^2 + b^2 c}{b^2 + d^2}$

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=((x+-+a)+%2F+b)+%5E+2+%2B+((x+-+c)+%2F+d)+%5E+2++%3D+1+solve+for+x

However this can result in the root of a negative number, and resulting in a complex number, which is not what the paper seems to want. I am unsure on how to solve this (in code) to get a real value for x.

So my question is, how do i solve this equation as desired by the paper?

---

PS. Limiting  to real x still has the same problem

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=((x+-+a)+%2F+b)+%5E+2+%2B+((x+-+c)+%2F+d)+%5E+2++%3D+1+solve+for+real+x

Comment: There might not always be a real solution possible, if $a$ and $c$ are sufficiently distant from one another.   You can check for a negative, take the square root of the absolute value, then mark the result to indicate a complex value...

Comment: There are possible {a,b,c,d} for which there is no real solution. This occurs when a and c are far away from eachother. (See the $+2 ac$ in the root). There is nothing wrong with this. If you only want real solutions you should put a boundry on your inputs.

Comment: What exact part of the article you're trying to implement (page, row).

Comment: Ok, got it. Did you check if perhaps the conditions in the article prohibit negative roots. In light of my answer, if there is always an intersection?

Comment: They do say that when one of the terms is infinite you can drop it, maybe this can be interpreted as "so large that the root becomes negative".

Comment: They say something different. 

If either $m_x$ or $m_y$ is undefined because both neighbors have infinite cost, then we drop that dimension out of Equation (11)"

It means you are in a situation when you have $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$. Then you may not draw any intelligible number out of it.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the equation 
$\left(\frac{x-a}{b}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{y-c}{d}\right)^2 = 1$. It is an ellipsis centered at $(a,c)$ with axes parallel to origin of lengths $b$ and $d$ respectively. The solution of your task are the points where this ellipsis intersects with the line $y=x$. There may be no intersection - and that is exactly the case of complex roots.

Answer (score 1):

It's $$d^2(x^2-2ax+a^2)+b^2(x^2-2cx+c^2)=b^2d^2$$ or
$$(b^2+d^2)x^2-2(d^2a+b^2c)x+a^2d^2+b^2c^2-b^2d^2=0,$$ which gives
$$x=\frac{d^2a+b^2c\pm\sqrt{(d^2a+b^2c)^2-(b^2+d^2)(a^2d^2+b^2c^2-b^2d^2)}}{b^2+d^2}$$ or
$$x=\frac{d^2a+b^2c\pm\sqrt{d^4a^2+2b^2d^2ac+b^4c^2-b^2a^2d^2-b^4c^2+b^4d^2-d^4a^2-b^2c^2d^2+d^4b^2}}{b^2+d^2}$$ or
$$x=\frac{d^2a+b^2c\pm bd\sqrt{2ac-a^2-c^2+b^2+d^2}}{b^2+d^2}.$$
We need $b^2+d^2\neq0$ and $2ac-a^2-c^2+b^2+d^2\geq0$.

Thus, for the biggest root we obtain:
$$x=\frac{d^2a+b^2c+bd\sqrt{2ac-a^2-c^2+b^2+d^2}}{b^2+d^2}.$$